# change char-set of page with jquery

Tags: jquery, character-encoding

can i change the char-set of the page in jquery ?

i need it , because i support old system  that not use utf-8.

on user click  i want to show different language form .

It is text that come via ajax

I CAN GET IT BUT COULD NOT CHANGE IT :

```
var meta = $("meta").attr("content");
alert(meta);
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the charset is fixed for a document. However, you can dynamically (with JavaScript, that is) insert any Unicode character like this:

```
document.write ('\u2200 browsers.'); // gives '∀ browsers'
```

The different language on user click: Is the text inserted via JavaScript (perhaps via AJAX), or is it another HTML page to be embedded somehow?

Cheers,

**Update:** It seems (I haven't tested it), that in IE you can actually *set* the charset via `document.defaultCharset`, although possibly this has only an effect, if there is no charset delivered with the HTML file. In Gecko based browsers (like Firefox) you can get the charset via `document.characterSet`.

Comment: It is text that come  via ajax